# Go to newly created post

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, forms

Once the user has made a valid post and pressed Post, I want them to be taken to the valid post. I ran a test with `return redirect('post-detail', 18)`. At the moment once a valid post had been made then the post with ID 18 is loaded.

I am trying to get the ID of the newly created post. What I am trying to write is `return redirect('post-detail', id of newly created post)`

As this line works `form.instance.author = self.request.user`, I tried `form.instance.id`
 but it didn't have the desired results.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user

    return redirect('post-detail', 18)

    #print (form.instance.id)
    return redirect('post-detail', form.instance.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not *save* the form, hence that means that at that point in time the object has no primary key yet. Normally the form is saved in the basic `form_valid` method.

You furthermore probably better override `get_success_url`, since that is the place where you are supposed to "calculate" the url to redirect to:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.object.pk])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        # will save the form and redirect to the success_url
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I am now getting the error message - The view blog.views.PostCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @RossSymonds: sorry, made a typo, you should `return` the `super().form_valid()` :)

Comment: Could you explain why 'return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.object.pk])' works but   'return redirect ('post-detail', args=[self.object.pk])' doesn't?

Comment: `return super().form_valid(form)`. What is the problem with `reverse`? You need to import it like on the first line of the code fragment.

Comment: When someone helped me yesterday, they used return redirect. I looked online for the difference between redirect and reverse, but only found an overly complicated answer which made little sense to me.

Comment: I accidentally posted my comment to soon. I then quickly tried to edit it.

Comment: @RossSymonds: `reverse` returns the *path* (as a string), `redirect` uses `reverse` and wraps it in a `HttpRedirect` response. But the `get_success_url` itself is supposed to return a string that contains the path, so here `reverse` should be used.